# sscanf Beginner in C

Tags: c, scanf

I want to take inputs in from a user, so a user will say something like
Name Age Age_of_brother Age_of_sister
So i can get an input like
"John 18"
or "John 18 20" or
"John 19 20 121"
anything of that sort.
so i know i can do
Assuming "command[80]" has my string

```
sscanf(command, "%s%d%d%d", string, &int1, &int2, &int3);
```

but i've tried that and when I compare int2 or int3 to NULL, it always ends up printing out a random integer for int2 or int3, even if it is de-referenced. So how do I approach this?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect that you are causing *undefined behavior* by passing pointer pointing to object having wrong type to `sscanf()`: `%d` expect `int*`, but you may be passing `int**` because you wrote  "even if it is de-referenced". Note that `int3` won't be affected because no format specifier for modifying it is there.

Comment: Checking for "int2 or int3 to NULL" is not the right thing to do. Firstly because those are (presumably) `int` types not pointers. And secondly, `sscanf` does not write to them if there is no match. Instead, you should read the [sscanf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to understand how it operates. In particular the section on the return value: "These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure."

Comment: Your format specifies 1 string and 2 integers.  Your argument list appears to be passing 1 string (char) pointer and 3 integer pointers.  Which is it, 2 integers as your format indicates, or 3 integers as your argument list indicates?  As it stands, `int3` will not be affected by the `scanf` call.

Comment: 1) Post the definitions of `string, int1, int2, int3`.  2) When code runs, what is the return value of `sscanf()`?  Checking that will solve most of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@n.Doe,

What you might be experiencing is that the variables aren't being initialized and thus see some random values when the sscanf() doesn't get to find the content for those missing ones. Try initializing them as following.

```
int int1 = 0, int2 = 0, int3 = 0;
```

Also, the sscanf() needs the variables addresses (hence you use &var) in order to be able to update the contents referred by them in the memory. So don't de-reference them while printing the values held by them or when comparing them to zero (not NULL, which is meant to compare with pointers). Since the variables int1-3 are initialized you will see 0 being printed when the sscan() couldn't read into them.